# How do you deal with a categorical variable that has multiple levels?

Tags: machine-learning

Suppose we want to model whether somebody makes $> \$50,000$ or $< \$50,000$ based on various predictor variables. These variables can be either continuous or categorical. If a categorical variable has many levels, is there any way to account for this without having to create dummy variables?

For example, in a random forest or logistic regression, it could take a long time for these algorithms to run if you include a lot of dummy variables.

Answer (score 1):

Not so long as you keep treating it as categorical. Dummy variables (and other, trivially different coding schemes) are how categories are input as predictors to regression models. Doing something else with a predictor (in a regression model, at least) requires treating it as having a more than purely categorical structure.

Comment: This is correct, at least to my knowledge in SPSS, R and SAS.